# How to add a new child without over-writing other children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a new child to the below in my database but every time I add a new child the others are overwritten.

[image]

I'm aware setValue() will overwrite children. I don't want to use Push() as this will create another id which I don't want as I want users to be able to go into the database and add a new userID:true manually.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("readUsers")

HashMap<String, String> readUser = new HashMap<>();
                            readUser.put(userId, "true");


mDatabase.setValue(readUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
```

Is there another way I add new children without using push()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `updateChildren()`:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("readUsers")
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put(userId, "true");
mDatabase.updateChildren(updates);
```

From the docs:

> [Update specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)
>
> To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the `updateChildren()` method.

Comment: Perfect, that works. I can't believe I wasn't aware of updateChildren() all these months.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
mDatabase.setValue(readUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {}
```

to

```
mDatabase.updateChildren(readUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {}
```

See, instead of using `setValue()` method, I've used DatabaseReference's [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)):

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values.

Comment: Thanks Alex, marking Peter's as the answer as I wasn't aware I needed to change my hashMap from <String,String> to <String, Object>

Answer (score 1):

Just use `updateChildren()` in place of `setValue`. That's all you need. At the end, your update line would look like this:

```
mDatabase.updateChildren(readUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    //Your code
}
```

You can read the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)).

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!